# How to connect wireless mic (TRS output) to mixer (1/4 inch input)?

Tags: sound, mixing, microphones, audio, mixer

I'm having trouble connecting my wireless microphone (lavalier set) to an audio mixer. My wireless microphone is Saramonic Blink 500, which has TRS output on its receiver, and my audio mixer is Behringer Q502USB which has 1/4 inch jack input. So far I'm only using a simple TRS to 1/4 Inch to connect my TRS cable to mixer. I'm a beginner in audio engineering so I'm quite confused how to connect these things...

Anyway, I've tried to connect my saramonic directly to my laptop 3.5mm and it works with "Line In" type input.. Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 2):

The Behringer has a TRS input on channel 1 (Balanced input). The wiring is in the manual, but is as follows;

[image: Behringer TRS Wiring]

The same input on channel 1 can also be a mono input (unbalanced)

[image: Behringer Mono Wiring]

Your Blink 500 does NOT have balanced output on the receiver; it has a 3.5mm stereo output. The best solution is to find a 3.5mm 1/8" TRS to Dual 6.35mm 1/4" TS Mono Stereo Y-Cable Splitter cable, and then use channels 2/3 on the mixer for input. This will give you stereo on the mixer - any solution that uses just one cable will lose you either the left or right channel.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the manual for the wireless microphone to find out what the connections should be, in order to get the correct adaptor to suit the mixer.

TRS simply describes a plug/socket with three terminals.  Unfortunately, these plugs get used in several incompatible ways, including:

- Stereo audio: left/right/ground
- Balanced audio: positive/negative/ground
- Powered microphone: signal/power/ground

Comment: Thankyou so much... Seems like I have no clue about these things :( Maybe this simple image could help you understand what I mean...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T9T9Nb7tB44jA5QSRG6cl7gVWFJdVpma/view?usp=sharing

Anyway, I watched this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xK8oQcft6VA).. Is this possibly what I did wrong?

once again, thank you!

Comment: @JamesMarcus First problem: you're connecting a micriphone to the line in socket, so it will be very quiet.  Second problem, by using a TRS plug, the mixer thinks you have a balanced microphone.  You need a TRS-to-XLR adaptor and use the mic input.  **Do not turn on the phantom power**.

Comment: - "Ohhh, phantom!!" 
- "Woof"

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing terms a bit here - TRS means Tip, Ring, Sleeve, which is a connector for two signals + ground. These are often used as stereo connectos, but have other uses too. I presume that you have differently-sized mono (TR) connectors - minijack and full-sized (1/4 inch).

In any case, an adapter should be fine for this purpose. Maybe the settings on the mixer are wrong?

Comment: It can also be used for sending balanced signal, or for patching an effect. TRS are not only stereo cables ;)

Comment: @Tom_C True, I updated my answer

Comment: @Vegard Thankyou so much... Seems like I have no clue about these things :( Maybe this simple image could help you understand what I mean (drive.google.com/file/d/1T9T9Nb7tB44jA5QSRG6cl7gVWFJdVpma/). Shouldn't any wireless mic receiver be able to connect to any kind of mixer or soundcard??

Anyway, I watched this video (youtube.com/watch?v=xK8oQcft6VA).. Is this possibly what I did wrong? Once again, thank you!